# How to make changes in management concole regarding WSO2 Identity Server v5.0.0

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have download all patches (upto patch008), by using  TortiseSVN svn checkout  the following //svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/  and  //svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk11/

Then exported above folder to another location D:\platform, D:\productssource and build them with Build successful message !.

Now I want to makes changes in Management Console of WSO2IS v5.0 Under Entitlement Sub menu such as PAP, PDP and **MyOwnCreatedPAP**, which look like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZwvS.png).

To achieve above mentioned requirement, what steps should I followed in Eclipse IDE to makes changes in source code, plz mentioned them in step by step, as I am newbie.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to write a custom Carbon component UI bundle. You need to include a `component.xml` file in `src/main/resources/META-INF/` folder of your component with content similar to below to add a menu item.

```
<component xmlns="http://products.wso2.org/carbon">
    <menus>
        <menu>
            <id>studentmgt_menu</id>
            <i18n-key>student.menu</i18n-key>
            <i18n-bundle>org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.ui.i18n.Resources</i18n-bundle>
            <parent-menu>manage_menu</parent-menu>
            <link>../student-mgt/index.jsp</link>
            <region>region1</region>
            <order>50</order>
            <style-class>manage</style-class>
            <icon>../student-mgt/images/students.gif</icon>
            <require-permission>/permission/protected/manage</require-permission>
        </menu>
    </menus>
</component>
```

Follow [this guide](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2014/03/how-to-write-a-wso2-carbon-component/) for a complete tutoriol on how to write a custom Carbon component and create a UI bundle.

Comment: I am not going to create a totally new component. Rather, I am going to insert new item in already defined components (ie. Identity Server v 5.0.0). Can you guide me in this context. ?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to edit the IS source to add a new menu item. Go through the "Writing the UI component" section in link given above and create a small component to add the menu item. You should be able to achieve your requirement without making changes in the IS source code.